# MEX can't locate VS Express 2013 compiler - MATLAB R2013a

Tags: c++, matlab, visual-studio-2012, mex

While setting up `mex` on my machine using `mex -setup -v`, VS Express 2013 compiler can't be found

[image]

for some reasons (see above screenshot). I still have VS 2010 installed on my machine, but I'd like to have the option to select the Express 2013 compiler on `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\` . Has someone experienced such an issue so as to share his experience?

Thanks

Comment: I did not experience exactly this stuff, but I remember something abouit express compiler being not supported by matlab. You can check in the list of supported compilers to be sure.

Comment: @HennadiiMadan: i think you're right as Express versions are  not displayed there (http://fr.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2015b/index.html). Although i will test test, do you think that `.dll, .lib, .h, .ctf` created using vs 10  compiler could be used in projects involving vs express 12?

Comment: not sure about  .ctf but the rest should be perfectly fine

Comment: added an answer so that there is something to accept

Comment: @HennadiiMadan:cheers && no worries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express Visual Studio compilers are not supported by Matlab.